# Script to control Roku box not working

Tags: javascript, php, curl, http-post, roku

A Roku box can be externally controlled through a simple, RESTful service accessed via the http protocol on port 8060, [see here](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/External+Control+Guide#ExternalControlGuide-32ExternalControlProtocolExamples). The commands I need to perform are sent via a POST with no body. They provide command line curl examples, like:

```
$ curl -d '' http://192.168.1.134:8060/keypress/home
```

I need to write this as a PHP script that will execute a series of actions: keypress/home, launch/appid, keypress/select, keypress/right, keypress/right, keypress/select.

See below for what I came up with for one command.  Two questions:

**1) My Roku is not responding to this, so what am I doing wrong?

2) What's the best way to send multiple POST requests one after the other?**

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('http://192.168.1.134:8060/keypress/home');
$data = '';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Try setting the url:  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://192.168.1.134:8060/keypress/home')

Comment: Tried that, still no response from the Roku.

Comment: Do you see any response when you try the same thing in a browser?

Comment: I've been testing it in a browser. No response. It takes about 1.5 minutes for the script to run, which seems long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better way to do it, client-side with javascript.

```
<script>
function post1() {
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.onload=function()
{
    alert(xhr.responseText);
}
xhr.open("POST", "http://192.168.1.134:8060/keypress/home");
xhr.send(); 
}
</script>
<body onload="post1()">
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to do it, your web/PHP server should be able to directly access your Roku, which is not typically the case. Is the server on the same network 192.168.1.* ?

Try http://remoku.tv/ to see if your Roku can be directly controlled form the browser.